# How to add 20% to number product page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a simple way to add 20% to the DKK amount of code below via jquery or JavaScript.

```html
<div id="priceInfo">

<span id="ctl00_bc_lblHtmlVariantPrice"><div class="current price"><span class="first">195,00 DKK</span></div>
```

I have tried div., But can not get it to work.

Hope can help

Comment: Do you mean 20% of 195?

Comment: It is to a shop product page where I 'vat' is not corrected properly. Yes, It should add 20% vat to 195

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. You just set the variable `percentage` to what percentage discount you desire. It also works if you were to add more price labels. Just make sure they have the class `.price`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var percentage = 20;
  $('.price').each(function(){
    var cur = parseFloat($(this).text());
    $(this).text(cur*(1-(percentage/100))+" DKK");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="ctl00_bc_lblHtmlVariantPrice"><div class="current price"><span class="first">195,00 DKK</span></div>
```

Comment: Hey Gustaf, is it also possible to change variants price on same page - code look like this: <label for="ctl00_bc_ocCtrl_oc-7310_0">17cm (195,00 DKK)</label>
<label for="ctl00_bc_ocCtrl_oc-7310_1">18cm (195,00 DKK)</label>
<label for="ctl00_bc_ocCtrl_oc-7310_2">19cm (195,00 DKK)</label>

Comment: @peter Now it seems like you're using labels, so add the class `.price` to all of them. Then you need to use regex to get the price inside the `(`..`)`. Or maybe you could put the price itself in a `<span>` and add the class `.price` to those instead.

Comment: I can not access the code directly, do you know if there is another way to add the class or do it

Comment: I can add class with jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
jQuery( "label" ).addClass( "price" );}); ... but i does't change the price

Comment: Make sure to add that class before you run my code above. Have you come up with a regex to extract the price inside `(..)`? @peter

Comment: No, I can not get it to work, I have tried with this code.`/**/
//TEST - VARIANT SIMPLE
/*remove parenthesis */
$('label').text(function(_, text) {
    return text.replace(/\(|\)/g, '');
});

/*add class to lable*/
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
jQuery( "label" ).addClass( "current price" );

});


/* FIX SIMPLE VARIANT PRICE*/
$(document).ready(function(){
  var percentage = 25;
  $('.current.price').each(function(){
    var cur = parseFloat($(this).text());
    $(this).text(cur*(1+(percentage/100))+" DKK");
  });
});

// END`
It works fine on the price at the top, but not the labels..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="priceInfo">

<span id="ctl00_bc_lblHtmlVariantPrice"><div class="current price"><span class="first"><span class="amount">195,00</span> DKK</span></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e){

    var subTotal = parseFloat($("#ctl00_bc_lblHtmlVariantPrice .amount").text());
    var total = subTotal + (subTotal * 0.2);
    alert(total);

});
</script>
```

Comment: Well yes, but can easily be implemented to work with other elements!